# Explanation of Android Xfermode

Tags: android, graphics, xfermode

I'm newbie in graphics and there is really raw explanation of `Xfermode` class in Android documentation for me.

Searching the web, I found only relation with such terms like: color blending, image compositing, small explanation about Transfer modes algorithms, source color, destenation color and op color (that means opacity color if I'm not wrong). But it didn't give me enough understanding.

Is there anybody who could explain me this terms, or better give me a link where I can study their explanation?

Comment: U can check this video from Romain Guy and Chet Haase. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duefsFTJXzc&feature=results_video&playnext=1&list=PL01724209851DF753

Answer (score 12):

I found this really good explanation: [PorterDuff Modes and Android](http://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/1009/)

Comment: Glad you liked my explanation :-)

Answer (score 5):

It basically contains the different layouts of how 2 images can be laid out.

For better read try this link out to :  [explanation](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html)

Answer (score 4):

Xfermode is use for describe the drawing relationship of two bitmaps, with different Xfermode option for example you can draw a round image with radius corners or a circle image, you can find the sample in the follow android sdk directory:\your_sdk_directory\samples\android-8\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\graphics